# Using sql subquery in Tableau

Tags: sql, subquery, tableau-api, calculated-field

I trying to calculate a new field in Tableau similar to a sub query in SQL. However, my numbers not matching up when I try to do this. I am stuck at this point and I am trying to see what others have done.

To provide reference, below is the subquery that I am trying to duplicate in Tableau.

```
 select
 ((sum(n.non_influenced_sales*n.calls)/sum(n.calls))-(sum(n.average_sales*calls)/sum(calls))))/
      (sum(n.non_influenced_sales*n.calls)/sum(n.calls)) as impact
 from (select
 count(d.id) as calls
 ,avg(d.sale) as average_sales
 ,avg(case when non_influenced=1 then d.sale else null end) as non_influenced_sales
 from data d
 group by skill) n
```

When I try to build the same calculation in Tableau, I am able to get the same results as long as I comment out the group by skill. However, when I try to group by skill, my attempts to match the number have not been working.

The closest I have come is when I try to fix the level of detail expression by using include. Tableau code:

```
(include [skill]:([non_influenced_sales]-[average_sales])/[non_influenced_sales]}
```

However, doing this or using fixed has not worked and I can't match the numbers I am getting from SQL.

FYI, Impact is an aggregated measure. I built the sub-query part in tableau by just creating separate fields for the calculation I needed. So for example
Non Influenced Sales calculated in Tableau:

```
avg(if [non_influenced]=1 then [non_influenced_sales] end)
```

However, I am not sure if this matters or not.

I have also tried creating custom sql. I am able to get a rolled up version using all of the dates correct. But when I want to get down to different dates/use other filters, things get messy real quick. I am trying to build relationships on a date level, but that hasn't worked either.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Please post some sample data of your current Tableau and SQL results for us to visualize why numbers don't match.

Comment: @Parfait the results are only slightly off and its because of the group by. Without group by: both results come out to 4.4% with group by sql: 5.8% tableau: 6.3% with the include.